# Al revisar vía web, el texto de los votos se encabalga con el de las publicaciones

Tags: bug, colas-de-revisión, diseño, web-móvil

Acabo de tener la osadía de revisar vía móvil. Muy complicado todo, pero fui tirando...

Lo que vi al encontrarme con la revisión https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/91545 es que el texto de los votos se encabalga con el cuerpo de la publicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy en:

- Android 5
- Chrome 65
- bq Aquaris E5 HD (es un modelo con pantalls pequeñita)

Comment: No-repro. Estoy seguro de que como todo en mobile depende de dispositivo y navegador. Estaría bueno que lo agregues.

Comment: @Mariano gracias. Añadido

Comment: Recién actualicé de 64 a Chrome/65.0.3325.109 y deja *muchísimo* menos espacio que antes ([captura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4In2.png)) en Google Pixel; Android 8.1.0.

Comment: ¿Qué dispositivo estás usando? Los estilos para dispositivos móviles esconden la opción de revisión, por lo que supongo que no le habrán dado estilos especiales para pantallas pequeñas. Pero en ese caso, ¿es realmente un fallo de diseño del texto?¿o es un fallo a la hora de detectar el dispositivo móvil?

Comment: @Alvaro sí, realmente la web móvil no está preparada para revisar, tuve que ir manualmente a /review, que utiliza el diseño de web normal. Uso BQ Aquaris E5 HD, un modelo algo viejo.

Comment: De todas formas, el cambio entre Chrome 64 y 65 fue *muy* significativo. Me hubiese gustado sacar una captura antes de actualizar... Veía algo así como 150px de espacio, y pasó a casi 0. Yo creo que esto es algo que no estaba planeado y que seguramente haya que corregir.